# I was trying to perform a combined query using the parse sdk for flutter and I am not sure how to do it

Tags: parse-platform, flutter

Can someone help with performing combined queries using the flutter Parse server sdk

```
 var queryName = QueryBuilder(ParseObject('_User'))
    .whereStartsWith("full_name", queryString); 

 var queryEmail = QueryBuilder(ParseObject('_User'))
    .whereStartsWith("email", queryString);
```

how would i combine these two queries?

Comment: You are unlikely to get help here as the Flutter SDK is unofficial and doesn’t have a SO tag. I would think you may have more luck on their [slack group](http://flutter-parse-sdk.slack.com/).

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, you figured out how to use compound queries?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

````
var query = QueryBuilder(ParseObject('_User'))
    ..whereStartsWith("full_name", queryString)
    ..whereStartsWith("email", queryString);```
````